# How to Redirect to a URL In a Java/Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-11

I am building a URL shortener and am working on the "follow method" - e.g. short.li/?stub=dishpods should redirect to  [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07CTQ8THP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CTQ8THP)

How do I set up this automatic redirect in my controller? The best I've been able to figure out is printing to the console, but I want it to automatically follow.

```
  @GetMapping("/")
    void follow(@RequestParam String stub) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ShortUrl longUrl = repository.findByShortUrl(stub);
        String longUrlString;
        if (longUrl != null) {
            longUrlString = longUrl.getShortUrl();
        } else {
            longUrlString = "https://google.com";
        }

        try {

            URL myurl = new URL(longUrlString);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            StringBuilder content;

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {

                String line;
                content = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    content.append(line);
                    content.append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }

            System.out.println(content.toString());

        } finally {

            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use springs [RedirectView](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html):

```
@GetMapping("/")
public RedirectView follow() {
    return new RedirectView("www.foo.baa");
}
```

Comment: setting contextrelative=false with that was just what I needed! Thanks

Comment: Should be false by default to my knowledge, but I only ever used it for relative paths. Glad it helped!